# Server side rendering using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering, react-ssr

I have started to work on react server side rendering, Having some questions i.e how about routing and can i implement server side rendering for all pages in application,Please provide any example on server side rendering in reactjs,Thanks

Answer (score 0):

for plain implementation in server side rendering you need to have different app entry point with StaticRouter instead of BrowserRouter
react-routed-dom documentation with implementation:
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/server-rendering/putting-it-all-together